# Excerpt for each post type and for is_front_page

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, excerpt

i try to adjust the excerpt for each post type and especially for the front page.

```
function isacustom_excerpt_length($length) {
global $post;
if (is_front_page() || is_home()){

    if ($post->post_type == 'news')
            return 200;
        else if ($post->post_type == 'projects')
            return 150;
        else if ($post->post_type == 'term')
             return 75;
         else
            return 80;
}else {
      if ($post->post_type == 'news')
            return 20;
        else if ($post->post_type == 'projects')
            return 80;
        else if ($post->post_type == 'term')
             return 75;
         else
            return 80;

}};   add_filter('excerpt_length', 'isacustom_excerpt_length');
```

The problem is that the if (is_front_page() || is_home()) is never true.

thx for the help!!!

Comment: `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` do work. They are just not `true` where you think they should be `true`. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99702/21376 The two functions can be tricky.

Comment: so i should use only "is_front_page()"

Comment: I can't answer that. I don't know what conditions you need as you haven't provided that information.

Comment: ahh, ok 
I solved it.

instead of is_front_page or is_home is use "$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == /"

Comment: Your solution may not work if Wordpress is not installed in the root directory. Using `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` correctly is the most appropiate way to go.

Comment: Agreed with @cybnet. Your solution will fail in some circumstances.