# how to hide or disable some part in specify page

Tags: php

i want from my footer.php file some part like `<div class="form">----------</div>` this part will be visible all page but not show in home page and few other other. i think it is possible via use php condition.

i read [is_home, and is_front_page conditional problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/is-home-and-is-front-page-conditional-problem) but that way not also work

```
<?php if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() ) {
echo "Hello World";
} else {

echo "Else World";
}
?>
```

for all page even home page i am getting Hello World. i tried
 `<?php if ( ( is_page('home')) ) {` 
also `<?php if ( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {` 
also `<?php if(is_page(248)){`

not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to "reverse" your logic, in a sense. You need "not (home or front)", not "not home and not front". For example:

```
// var_dump(is_home(),is_front_page(),(is_home() || is_front_page()),!(is_home() || is_front_page())); // debug
if ( !(is_home() || is_front_page()) ) {
  echo "Hello World";
} else {
  echo "Else World";
}
```

An easier, more readable way to write the same thing is:

```
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
  echo "Else World";
} else {
  echo "Hello World";
}
```

Please be aware that the`is_home()` and `is_front_page()` functions [can be confusing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99702/21376).

Comment: thank u so much. i tried both your code. copy and paste to footer.php.. home page and all other other page i am getting Hello World. very much confusing

Comment: Uncommented the `var_dump` line. Do you ever get a `true` for worker is the first two values?

Comment: home page and rest of page i am getting this message bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(true) Hello World

Comment: So neither `is_home()` nor `is_front_page()` ever returns `TRUE`. Something about the way your theme is built (or a lugin in interfering) is causing problems. Your code will never work until you figure out why. That is, you need to figure out the page logic of your theme before you will be able to get done what you want to do. I can't guess at what that logic is.

Comment: The code I posted, by the way, works on my test install with a bundled Twenty-something theme.

Comment: thank u so much for your kind info. i am thinking also same. but i am not so expert on wordpress yet. before someone did this theme now i need to do something on it. if you can then please see my function.php http://pastebin.com/wwx2GRpZ is there have anything or not, installed plugins are
BJ Lazy Load
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP
MyMail - Email Newsletter Plugin
Scroll Back to Top
UberMenu 2 - WordPress Mega Menu Plugin 
WordPress Importer

Comment: I didn't spot anything obvious, sorry. I don't know how to guess at how your theme was built, again sorry. This answer is the correct logic though, given the information in the question. I wish I could do more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `page id` as mentioned by @vee s answer.
For Eg: If you want to echo `Hello world` on front page, page id 1, and 2 with echo `Else world` for all other pages, use:

```
<?php 
if ( ( is_front_page() ) && ( is_page(1) || is_page(2) ) ) {
    echo "Hello World";
} else {
    echo "Else world";
?>
```

For more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<?php 
if ( (!is_front_page() ) && (is_page (14) || is_page(25) || .... ) ) 
{
    echo "Hello World";
} 
?>
```

Comment: it work <?php 
if ( (!is_front_page() ) && (is_page (92) ) ) 
{
    echo "Hello World";
} 
?>   but it only effect on home page and 92 id. mean hello  world don't show in home page but show in 92 page and rest of page not show. i want home not show and 92 not show and rest of page will show.

Comment: Okay, In that case just put ! before for the you want to hide. Like : <?php if ( (!is_front_page() ) && (!is_page (92) || .. other pages to hide ) ) { echo "Hello World"; } ?>


This process is lengthy, instead of this you can create two page templates and select from admin, or you can create the form in sidebar and display/hide the sidebar using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/

Using the hard coded way is not recommended, thus page template or option is recommended. Share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Put all the page Ids in an array for which you do not want to show the div. Try the following code.

```
global $post;
$posts_array = array(1);
$current_page_id = $post->ID;

if ( (! is_front_page() ) && (  ! in_array( $current_page_id, $posts_array ) ) ) {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: i have more than 195 pages. it hard put all page id thats why i want like this way